# Meaning of "improved" when used as an adjective to compare between two different things?

Tags: adjectives, comparisons

I encountered this sentence today while translating form english:

> These alloys lack the crystallinity of conventional engineering alloys, and some of their properties —such as higher yield stress and elastic strain limit— are greatly improved relative to their crystalline counterparts.

What would be the meaning of improved here? Does it simply mean better? Which means that their properties are much better than that of the crystalline ones?
Or the comparison here is between the level of improvement of the properties of the two types of alloys?

Comment: Yes, it just means better. To improve something means to make it better, so "improved" as an adjective means that it's the result of that action.

Comment: You need to add context (doubtless that these alloys have been _developed_. So 'improved' means 'made better' (though just 'better' is acceptable) (and 'relative to their crystalline counterparts' could more crudely be written 'than their crystalline counterparts'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't rephrase the English here, I am just trying to figure out the meaning to understand it properly. the context pretty much conveys the meaning that the first alloys are better in these properties. Besides, if the intending meaning was to compare the improvement of the two types, wouldn't the writer use "have been improved relative to" instead?

Comment: Without confirmation that prior text contains something to the effect of 'these new alloys are made by a novel process' (or not), one can't say whether 'made better' or just 'better' is more appropriate. // Not necessarily.

Comment: @edwin ashworth I totally agree, just wanted to make sure that there is no decisive rule here. Thanks so much

Comment: As I stated elsewhere, the 'is now better' sense for _improve_ is available (The weather conditions are greatly improved) as well as the 'has been made better' (The design is now improved). With 'Their properties are greatly improved', either reading is possible, but it's likely that human development was involved (thus the 'have been made better' sense, but this paraphrase is poor here).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Barmar.  "Improved" does not mean "better" it means "made better".

Comment: In 'The weather has improved', it just means 'become better'. And 'Thanks to the improved weather conditions, we were able to sail' is acceptable.

Comment: @packard wouldn't the writer use "have been improved" if the intended meaning was "made better"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/362653)

Comment: @jimm101 This is a serious attempt to answer the question although it also contains an opinion. If you believe it is wrong, downvote it. Don't use the review process to suggest deleting poor but sincere answers. It could be improved by quoting a reputable source.